# R function for transforming degrees to cardinal points

Tags: r

I've written a function in R that allows me to transform a degree (degree of arc) to a cardinal point (N, W, S, ...).

```
degree2cardinal <- function(x) {
    upper <- seq(from = 11.25, by = 22.5, length.out = 17)
    upper <- append(upper, rep(NA, times=5)) 
    card1 <- c('N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW', 'N', '', '-', '--', '---', 'NA')
    compare <- x<=upper
    card1[which(compare)][1]
}
```

I've added come common symbols that appear instead of `NA`. It works albeit somewhat slowly and I beleive there **must be a faster way of doing this**. The input for the function is any positive double from `0` to `360`.

I'll provide an example of a comparable size.

```
> set.seed(360)
> deg <- sample(x = seq(from = 0, to = 360, by=0.01), 400000, replace=T) 
> system.time(sapply(deg, degree2cardinal))
 user  system elapsed 
14.45    0.00   14.96
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the function `findInterval`, which will make your code 40-50 times faster:

```
d2c.2 <- function(x) {
  upper <- seq(from = 11.25, by = 22.5, length.out = 17)
  card1 <- c('N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW', 'N')
  ifelse(x>360 | x<0,NA,card1[findInterval(x,upper,rightmost.closed = T)+1])
}
```

Note that I don't deal with 'common symbols' in my solution.

```
library(rbenchmark)
set.seed(360)
deg <- sample(x = seq(from = 0, to = 360, by=0.01), 40000, replace=T) 
d2c.sapply <- function(z) sapply(z, degree2cardinal)


benchmark(d2c.sapply(deg),d2c.2(deg))
#              test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 2      d2c.2(deg)          100   1.507    1.000     1.339    0.168          0         0
# 1 d2c.sapply(deg)          100  66.576   44.178    65.749    0.620          0         0
```

Comment: I've replicated the tests and tried out your function and it works very well.